# Why the DHCP provide us our subnet?

Tags: subnet, dhcp, lan

I'm trying to learn the DHCP protocol and the importance of what he gives to the computers connected to him.

If I send everything through the router, why I need the DHCP to provide me the subnet of my LAN?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use DHCP and staticly assigned IP addresses to machines. But in some networks like client access network that could be very difficult task to maintain is why we are using DHCP. Please below why you should use DHCP.

```
Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) is a client/server protocol that automatically provides an Internet Protocol (IP) host with its IP address and other related configuration information such as the subnet mask and default gateway.

RFCs 2131 and 2132 define DHCP as an Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) standard based on Bootstrap Protocol (BOOTP), a protocol with which DHCP shares many implementation details. DHCP allows hosts to obtain necessary TCP/IP configuration information from a DHCP server.

Benefits of DHCP:

Reliable IP address configuration. DHCP minimizes configuration
   errors caused by manual IP address configuration, such as
   typographical errors, or address conflicts caused by the assignment
   of an IP address to more than one computer at the same time.

Reduced network administration. DHCP includes the following features to reduce network administration: 

 - Centralized and automated TCP/IP configuration
 - The ability to define TCP/IP configurations from a central location.
 - The ability to assign a full range of additional TCP/IP configuration
   values by means of DHCP options.
 - The efficient handling of IP address changes for clients that must be
   updated frequently, such as those for portable computers that move to
   different locations on a wireless network.
 - The forwarding of initial DHCP messages by using a DHCP relay agent,
   thus eliminating the need to have a DHCP server on every subnet.

Why use DHCP
Every device on a TCP/IP-based network must have a unique unicast IP address to access the network and its resources. Without DHCP, IP addresses must be configured manually for new computers or computers that are moved from one subnet to another, and manually reclaimed for computers that are removed from the network.

DHCP enables this entire process to be automated and managed centrally. The DHCP server maintains a pool of IP addresses and leases an address to any DHCP-enabled client when it starts up on the network. Because the IP addresses are dynamic (leased) rather than static (permanently assigned), addresses no longer in use are automatically returned to the pool for reallocation.

The network administrator establishes DHCP servers that maintain TCP/IP configuration information and provide address configuration to DHCP-enabled clients in the form of a lease offer. The DHCP server stores the configuration information in a database, which includes:

 - Valid TCP/IP configuration parameters for all clients on the network.
 - Valid IP addresses, maintained in a pool for assignment to clients, as well as excluded addresses.
 - Reserved IP addresses associated with particular DHCP clients. This allows consistent assignment of a single IP address to a single DHCP client.
 - The lease duration, or the length of time for which the IP address can be used before a lease renewal is required.
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the quick answer! I asked why the dhcp sends the subnet. Not why should we use dhcp. Thanks!

Comment: Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) is a client/server protocol that automatically provides an Internet Protocol (IP) host with its IP address and other related configuration information such as the subnet mask and default gateway. It was created to do this Subnet is part of configuration supplied by DHCP server. Please rephrase your question than for what exactly do you want to know.

Comment: As a postscript to what he has mentioned above, I believe another way to think about it is that through administration of your dhcp scopes you are allowing yourself another measure of security and segmentation in your network environments. As with layer 2 and the use of Vlans for segmentation DHCP can be thought of in the same way to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

When a host needs to send some data to another host, the sending host must determine whether the receiving host is on the same network or not.

The sending host uses its own IP address and mask information to calculate whether the receiving host is on the same network. If it is, it sends the data direct to the host, if not, it will send the data towards its default gateway.